# how to change form field container div class?

Tags: html, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I using symfony2.5. I change form field container div class.

generated form fields:

```
<div>                
     <label for="ddd" class="required">lname</label>
     <input type="text" id="acme_demobundle_default_lname" name="acme_demobundle_default[lname]"   required="required">
</div>

 <div>                
     <label for="dddd" class="required">fname</label>
     <input type="text" id="acme_demobundle_default_fname" name="acme_demobundle_default[fname]"   required="required">
</div>
```

I add class to there are input`s container div.

any idea thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question/problem. Do you want to add a `class="something"` attribute to the container `<div>`s?

Comment: yes. I create form: $builder
            ->add('lname')
            ->add('fname');
in view: {{ form(form)}}

Answer (score 0):

You can set attributes using the form builder inside your controller

```
$builder->add('lname', 'text', array('attr' => array('class'=>'something')))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this in your form:

```php
$builder->add('name')
```

In your template you should use the functions:

```
{{ form_label(form.name) }} {# access the label #}
{{ form_widget(form.name) }} {# access the input field #}
```

You can wrap that up with your div and style it however you want:

```
<div class="your-class">
    {{ form_label(form.name) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
</div>
```

You can check more on [How to Customize Form Rendering](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html)